# Why don't instant noodles ooze oil

Tags: noodles, ramen

If instant noodles have been prepared by flash frying noodles, why are they not oily? Why don't you get any oil on your hands when you hold a "cake" of dry noodles?

Comment: I don't know about ramen, but my understanding is that potato chips are vibrated to try to remove a much of the oil as possible.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the answer but they still can have a certain amount of oiliness to them. If you break them up some and put them in a small paper bag, folding the top down and taping it shut (to keep out any small bugs or dust), you'll see oil stains on the paper bag after a couple of days. I'm referring to Asian-type nodes too, nit the Westernized version. I don't store them this way but was once curious to know.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia, "The dried noodle block was originally created by flash frying cooked noodles, and this is still the main method used in Asian countries, but air-dried noodle blocks are favored in Western countries."  (from   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_noodle   ) So I don't know where you are, but if it happens to be a "Western country", maybe that's why.

Comment: I've found ramen available without oil (was looking for it for a friend), but it seemed different from the stuff as the stuff that you can get 4 for a $1.  It was actually sold just as a block of noodles, not as an instant soup.  (no flavoring with it, etc)

Comment: I read this bit, and I'm talking about Asian countries.